# directionallight three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am fairly new to three.js. I put together a few things using r55 and wanted to add lights. I've been trying to add a DirectionalLight according to Mrdoob's documentation - no luck... The light that I try to add does not show up - added shadowCameraVisible for debugging but it just won't show up...  Anybody any idea what could be wrong with my code??? I appreciate any input!!

```
function init() {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //CUBE
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    });
    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(x, y, z);
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube.position.z = z / 2;
    scene.add(cube);

    //FLOOR
    //floor color:
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xcccccc
    });
    //floor size:
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 1, 1);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.position.y = -0.5;
    floor.doubleSided = true;
    scene.add(floor);

    //LIGHTS
    var dLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    dLight.position.set = (0, 0, 1);
    dLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
    dLight.shadowCameraNear = 1;
    dLight.shadowCameraFar = 150;
    dLight.castshadow = true;
    scene.add(dLight);

    //CAMERA POSITION
    camera.position.z = 50;
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dLight.position.set = (0,0,1);
```

Whoops, that doesn't look right... after this runs, the light position will NOT be a 3D vector, which will generate `NaN` from any math done with the light position.

```
dLight.position.set(0,0,1);
// or
dLight.position = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
```

Comment: True, that doesnt seem right... still, after changing that no light shows up... maybe something with the renderer settings?

Answer (score 1):

You set the light by

```
light.position.set (0,0,1);
```

But I think your light is inside the geometry.
Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/aSt8c/. It has a working directional light with shadow.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the fiddle, also found this one http://jsfiddle.net/Rhtr2/58/ but even with changing the position around I just do not seem to be able to make the light show up...

Answer (score 0):

The point is, that the material of your object have to be MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial. Other materials can't reflect the light.

`//CUBE
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    });
OR
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    });`

MeshPhongMaterial can be used for shiny, MeshLambertMaterial for non-shiny(Lambertian) surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set this:
floor.receiveShadow = true;

Comment: Yeah， and the material can not be MeshBasicMaterial， should be MeshPhongMaterial or others support light model.